# Find operating system and machine type in Chez Scheme

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

How can a Chez Scheme program or library find out which operating system and machine architecture it's running on (from within Scheme code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Chez Scheme Version 9 User's Guide](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/):

### Section 6.10. Bytevectors

```
(native-endianness)             import (rnrs) or (rnrs bytevectors)
```

### Section 12.4. Compilation, Evaluation, and Loading

```
(machine-type)                  import (chezscheme)
```

### Section 12.15. Environmental Queries and Settings

```
(scheme-version)                import (chezscheme)
(scheme-version-number)         import (chezscheme)
(petite?)                       import (chezscheme)
(threaded?)                     import (chezscheme)
(interactive?)                  import (chezscheme)
```

Unfortunately `(machine-type)` is a cryptic string idiomatic to Chez (instead of a standard symbol like `x86-64`) and may change from version to version. The other procedures work in the obvious manner.

I found these in the [r7rs-benchmarks](https://github.com/ecraven/r7rs-benchmarks/blob/master/src/Chez-postlude.scm) repo.

### Parsing the machine type

The machine type string is constructed as follows:

1. Start with an empty string.
2. For a build that supports threads, append the letter `t`.
3. Append the machine architecture.
4. Append the operating system.

Current architectures and operating systems:

```
(define arch-pairs
  '(("a6"    . amd64)
    ("arm32" . arm32)
    ("i3"    . i386)
    ("ppc32" . ppc32)))

(define os-pairs
  '(("fb"  . freebsd)
    ("le"  . linux)
    ("nb"  . netbsd)
    ("nt"  . windows)
    ("ob"  . openbsd)
    ("osx" . macos)
    ("qnx" . qnx)
    ("s2"  . solaris)))
```

To find all the machine types, look for all the makefiles named `Mf-*` in [the `c` directory of the Chez Scheme source repo](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/tree/master/c).